# How to add new test for onClick function using enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to write test case based on the condition, i want to check onClick functionality

condition to check

1. when props.item1 is true and props.item2 is false
2. when props.item1 is false and props.item2 is true
3. when props.item1 is true and props.item2 is true
4. when props.item1 is false and props.item2 is false

I want to know how to check the onClick function using this kind of condition

Here onclick is a function with type void   (onclick():void)

```
<Container>
  <span onClick={props.onClick || undefined}>{props.item}</span>
    { props.item1 && !props.item2 && (
      <span onClick={props.onClick || undefined}>Edit</span>
    )}
</Container>
```

here is testcase

```
describe('item list tests', () => {
  const props = {
  item: 'abc',
  item1: true,
  item2: false,
  onClick: () => jest.fn(),
}

test('prop values',() => {
  const output = shallow(<Header {...props} />)
  expect(output.find(Container).find('span')).toHaveLength(2)
  expect(output.find(Container).props().item1).toBe(true)
  expect(output.find(Container).props().item2).toBe(false)
 })
})
```

Error

```
 expect(output.find(Container).props().onClick).toBeCalled() //received value must be a mock or spy function
```

What are the other test case can be added here. for the above container component

Comment: I think a bit more context/background is necessary to think about more test cases.
And regarding the error you have to mock the onClick function, but i am not sure if you are looking to solve that.

Comment: @Rahul , yes i want to mock the on click function also, bit confused on this.

so for the particular container what are the test case i can add??that was the question

Comment: Can you give a broader picture of what exactly you want to do? may be I could help you with a better code design then.

Comment: Sure basically i need the container to be tested
i have a function onClick which of type Void
so in my props object i made it as onClick: () => jest.fn(),
Now i want  possible ways to test the container component

Comment: to make it simpler possible test case to test container component

Comment: no i mean , forget the code. Whats the functionality you want to test? like what do yo expect to happen on the UI. Also you name props better to make is easier to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224639/discussion-between-user13465472-and-rahul).

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not get the bigger picture, I can suggest only so much with the given information.

1. You could do something like this for example to check if spans are rendered based on props.

   `expect(wrapper.find({ id: 'element-id' }).exists()).toBeTruthy()`
2. If you want to perform a click action and check its result based on some internal state logic of header. you can do something like this in the test case

   ```
   props.onClick()


   //then check if the component is rendered or hidden
   expect(wrapper.find({ id: 'hidden-element' }).exists()).toBe(false)
   ```